# Resolving multiple Package.test test targets from SPM

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

It seems that if my library creates tests, and I also have a dependency with tests, then I get the error:

> :0: error: unable to build node: '' (node is produced by multiple commands; e.g., '' and '')

It can be seen in `debug.yaml`

```
test: [<Hummingbird.test.module>, <Vapor.test.module>, <Package.test>, <Package.test>]
```

If I rename one of the build targets to `Package2.test` manually in the `debug.yaml`, it works.

Is there a way that I can specify a test target name, or resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide example project or you folder and sources files layout?

Comment: @KostiantynKoval I was getting it w/ Vapor and any library that also included a Test folder, in this case, Hummingbird and Vapor. I ended up adding a build step to travis and general builds that deletes the `Tests` folder from all packages except current one, but I'd prefer to run all tests. My guess is that this will be resolved at some point as it seems like an SPM bug. I'll update the Q if / when that happens. If you have an answer in the meantime, I'd love it!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the implementation of how testing targets are derived, and it should now be fixed.